# How to read binary data in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm reading binary file http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon/productGraph/image_features/image_features.b
using pyspark.

```
import array
from io import StringIO

img_embedding_file = sc.binaryRecords("s3://bucket/image_features.b", 4106)

def mapper(features):
    a = array.array('f')
    a.frombytes(features)
    return a.tolist()

def byte_mapper(bytes):
    return str(bytes)

decoded_embeddings = img_embedding_file.map(lambda x: [byte_mapper(x[:10]), mapper(x[10:])])
```

When just `product_id` is selected from the rdd using

```
decoded_embeddings = img_embedding_file.map(lambda x: [byte_mapper(x[:10]), mapper(x[10:])])
```

The output for `product_id` is

```
["b'1582480311'", "b'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x88c-?\\xeb\\xe2'", "b'7@\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'", "b'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'", "b'\\xec/\\x0b?\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00K\\xea'", "b'\\x00\\x00c\\x7f\\xd9?\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'", "b'L\\xa6\\n>\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xfe\\xd4'", "b'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xe5\\xd0\\xa2='", "b'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'", "b'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'"]
```

The file is hosted on s3.
The file in each row has first 10 bytes for `product_id` next 4096 bytes as `image_features`
I'm able to extract all the 4096 image features but facing issue when reading the first 10 bytes and converting it into proper readable format.

Comment: "_but facing issue when reading the first 10 bytes_", can you add the issue/error you get?

Comment: @blackbishop added more info on that, I'm not able to decode the byte values for `product_id` but it is working fine for all the 4096 float array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Finally, the problem comes from the `recordLength`. It's not `4096 + 10` but `4096*4 + 10`. Chaging to :

```
img_embedding_file = sc.binaryRecords("s3://bucket/image_features.b", 16394)
```

Should work. 
Actually you can find this in the [provided code](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon/productGraph/) from the web site you downloaded the binary file:

```
for i in range(4096):
     feature.append(struct.unpack('f', f.read(4))) # <-- so 4096 * 4
```

**Old answer**:

I think the issue comes from your `byte_mapper` function. 
That's not the correct way to convert bytes to string. You should be using `decode`:

```
bytes = b'1582480311'
print(str(bytes))
# output: "b'1582480311'"

print(bytes.decode("utf-8"))
# output: '1582480311'
```

If you're getting the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 4: invalid start byte

That means `product_id` string contains non-utf8 characters. If you don't know the input encoding, it's difficult to convert into strings.

However, you may want to ignore those characters by adding option `ignore` to `decode` function:

```
bytes.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
```

Comment: I'm able to decode the first record, but it isn't working for rest of the records.

Comment: @tourist How do you know it's not working for the rest, you get errors? Also, could you add some records to the question so that we can reproduce it please?

Comment: I'm getting the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 4: invalid start byte`

Comment: Hemm so this means the input encoding isn't utf8. Please see my edit.

Comment: @bloackbishop, I'm not getting the error but the result is not decoded properly. I'm getting something like this `['1582480311', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88c-?ëâ', '7@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'ì/\x0b?\x00\x00\x00\x00Kê', '\x00\x00c\x7fÙ?\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'L¦\n>\x00\x00\x00\x00þÔ', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00åÐ¢=', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']`        This is for `ascii`, `utf-8` with `ignore` option

Comment: So now you decode the `product_id` correctly but not the `features`? Am I write? Did you see the example [in the source of your file](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/amazon/productGraph/) on how to unpack the features floats? (section **Read image features**). You may give it a try.

Comment: No, I'm able to load the floats but the `product_id` is not decoding properly. The above output I pasted is all product ids, I projected just on `product_id` and took 10 records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204233/discussion-between-blackbishop-and-tourist).